# Windows 8 - XAML - Conditional background for row in ListView

Tags: windows, xaml, listview, microsoft-metro

I have a data source with items in it. Each item has a boolean called "IsAvailable".
I want to render the datasource in a ListView. The background of each row must be green if "IsAvailable" = true or red if "IsAvailable" = false.

How can I do it?

Thanks

-- Marco

This is the code:

```
<ListView x:Name="frItemlistView" Margin="10,40,666,10" SelectionMode="None" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource availableItemsViewSource}}" IsSwipeEnabled="false" IsItemClickEnabled="True" ItemClick="frItemlistView_ItemClick_1" Grid.Row="1" DoubleTapped="frItemlistView_DoubleTapped_1" RightTapped="frItemlistView_RightTapped_1" BorderThickness="35,0,35,35" Grid.RowSpan="2">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Height="110" Margin="6">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,0,0,0">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Style="{StaticResource TitleTextStyle}" TextWrapping="NoWrap"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Subtitle}" Style="{StaticResource CaptionTextStyle}" TextWrapping="NoWrap"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Volume}" Style="{StaticResource BodyTextStyle}" MaxHeight="60"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding IsAvailable}" Style="{StaticResource BodyTextStyle}" MaxHeight="60" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use converter to do conditional formatting of `DataTemplate`. You need to bind `IsAvailable` property to background of `StackPanel`, converter will give appropriate color.

Add a class with this definition.

```
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI;

public class AvailabilityToColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        var Availability = (bool)value;
        var color = Availability ? new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green) : new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
        return color;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

XAML

`local` is the XAML namespace reference of `AvailabilityToColorConverter` class, which is in `<Page />`

```
<Page.Resources>
    <local:AvailabilityToColorConverter x:Key="AvailabilityToColor" />
</Page.Resources>

<ListView x:Name="frItemlistView" Margin="10,40,666,10" SelectionMode="None" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource availableItemsViewSource}}" IsSwipeEnabled="false" IsItemClickEnabled="True" ItemClick="frItemlistView_ItemClick_1" Grid.Row="1" DoubleTapped="frItemlistView_DoubleTapped_1" RightTapped="frItemlistView_RightTapped_1" BorderThickness="35,0,35,35" Grid.RowSpan="2">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Height="110" Margin="6">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,0,0,0" Background="{Binding IsAvailable, Converter={StaticResource AvailabilityToColor}}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Style="{StaticResource TitleTextStyle}" TextWrapping="NoWrap"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Subtitle}" Style="{StaticResource CaptionTextStyle}" TextWrapping="NoWrap"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Volume}" Style="{StaticResource BodyTextStyle}" MaxHeight="60"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding IsAvailable}" Style="{StaticResource BodyTextStyle}" MaxHeight="60" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: `Converter=AvailabilityToColor` this part is not correct, it should be `Converter={StaticResource AvailabilityToColor}`